# Why was this question on parsing a pdf closed?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

re: https://superuser.com/questions/822541/breaking-articles-into-sentences-for-easy-reading about breaking a pdf into sentences

The original wording of the question included the option for a software recommendation as a solution.  It was put on hold.  The question was edited to eliminate that problem and the edit was accepted.  Edits for questions on hold are not supposed to be accepted unless they solve the hold issue.  However, it was subsequently closed.  As currently written, the question looks like it fully conforms with the site's requirements and is a reasonable, useful question.  Is there another issue with it that needs to be corrected to re-open it?

Comment: It's since been deleted. Can a +10k'er grab a screenshot for us under the rep requirement to view it?

Comment: The handling of this question was inappropriate.  The original stated reason for putting it on hold was marginal, at best, and that issue was fixed.  The question was not off topic and as rewritten, complied with all of the site guidelines.  I asked a number of times for any other specific issues to be corrected and received no response.  I posted it here for community input and it was removed, apparently by a moderator, rather than allow community input, as the site provides.  A non-trivial amount of work and testing went into an answer to the question, which could be of general use.

Comment: it was autodeleted by the system, not by a Moderator. http://i.imgur.com/tO2xavO.png

Comment: The deleted page message said it was removed "for reasons of moderation", which seemed to imply that a human in a moderator role deleted it.  The FAQ page says that deleted answers are always available to the author, but that appears not to be the case.  It seems that once a question is put on hold, it is an automated system that leads to deletion unless humans intervene, and only luck prevents questions from slipping through the crack.  People should be less cavalier about voting to close and responsible to review fixes when they do.  The fact that it was autodeleted is no less frustrating.